# Hiding Running applications from dock

Tags: 16.04, dock

I am wondering how I can hide `Gkrellm` from the dock while it is running, as I plan to have it running all the time, and I don't want it cluttering the dock. I am running `16.04` with GNOME desktop.

Comment: i think it depend on application (Gkrellm) !!  some people report as a bug

Comment: try to search for setting in Gkrellm to does not show up in the gnome-panel

Answer (score 2):

You will find that under Gkrellm `settings --> general --> properties`, there is a check-box to hide it from the task-bar.

Comment: @Wilf don't be offended but i disagree with your review here, its in fact an answer from the questioner itself. I just edited it and now it makes sense as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This general solution also works and doesn't need an in-app property.

Do:

```
xprop | grep "CLASS"
```

and click on the window you want to remove from taskbar.

This will return something like

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "name", "name"
```

Install wmctrl

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

Make a program startup script or run once, depending on your preference:

```
wmctrl -x -r name.name -b add,skip_taskbar
```

Sources:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/798408/1520512
- https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6755
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133254
- Google