# Ubuntu GNOME - Hide running application in Dash.

Tags: gnome

So I have an application thats constantly running on the desktop.

When an application is running,  it shows up in the dash. I would like to hide it in the Dash, so in the Dash it looks like that it is not even running.  Is this possible?

To make it easier to understand, open terminal and run: sudo nautilus

It opens nautilus but is nowhere on the Dash. I would like to do the same thing to a specific application.

Comment: Unavoidably, running applications of the current user's x-session with a window appear in Dash, *unless* you unmap the window. Is it important the window is visibly present?

Comment: The thing is that I have a dock at the bottom. Im using a W7 VM as seamless mode in virtualbox. I made the startup script so far but the vbox icon is on the dash which I dont want.

Comment: Just pointing out to don't use sudo with graphical apps.

Comment: I know. But I am giving an example.

Comment: Would a shortcut key to toggle visibility be an option? Hidden means it would also not show an icon.

Comment: Application still has to be visible on desktop but not on dash.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not exist without breaking into the sourcecode and recompile. Not the kind of job we do here usually.

Comment: @JacobVlijm suggest something like `xdotool windowunmap $(wmctrl -l -p | grep $(pgrep procName) | cut -d' ' -f1)`, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/798408/349837) seems exactly what you want. Not tried on Wayland yet