# Hide Specific Running Applications from Dock (Side Bar) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I want to make secret recordings and I would like to hide only one application, for example, Cheese, which makes video recording. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: My version is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I used Unity only as a keyword.

Comment: And that was a wrong thing to do, it made the question confusing and  unclear. Ubuntu 18.04 comes with GNOME *instead of* Unity by default.

Comment: I can change the icon, but I can not hide it. With the command below `sudo gedit file:///usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Cheese.desktop`
I put after
`Icon=`
the address of an image I want.
Source: _https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BP3G92phH64_

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
xprop | grep "CLASS"
```

and click on the window you want to remove from taskbar.

This will return something like

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "name", "name"
```

Install wmctrl

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

Make a program startup script or run once, depending on your preference:

```
wmctrl -x -r name.name -b add,skip_taskbar
```

Sources:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/798408/1520512
- https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6755
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133254
- Google

Answer (score 1):

It is not a definitive solution but it works. I used the `dconf-editor` program to hide running applications, as shown in the image. Those that are running but I do not want to hide, as is the case of Google Chrome that appears in the image, I fixed it on the dock.

[image]